# Notifications when replies/ comments are posted in chat rooms?

Tags: discussion, chat, notifications

The comments and replies made on my own question/ answer or followed question go into my *INBOX* and the notification shows in the top right corner (right between the profile image and reputation image). Similar to this functionality, is there a way to get notified about unread "chat room" comments/ replies?

The reason I ask this is because for questions (with too many conversations) on which it is recommended to continue via chat rooms, the members may not be online all the time or would respond as soon as they find time. As of now, unless I go into the chat room, there is no way I can know whether there was any response. Ideally, if there is an item in my inbox indicating that there are new comments/ replies in the specific chat room, it would be a lot easier. This would be a really nice feature to have from user experience point of view.

Comment: @Ollie that requires someone pinging you, or using the reply function. Not all users do so, and for those messages you do not get a notification, while they are new activity in a chatroom.

Comment: There's no such thing, and pretty sure it was requested to add such a feature.

Comment: I agree with @Tinkeringbell. And, I think this question has been closed as duplicate without an actual relevant reason. The previous post (that supposed to provide the answer) talks more about the general reasons for not having the feature available and partial solutions only.